# Chainlink node not initializing, failed to initialize ORM: initializeORM#NewORM: unable to init DB: unable to open postgresql

Tags: chainlink, docker

I am trying to setup a chainlink node on my machine. After setting all the `.env` variables, I am running the docker command to start the node,

```
cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.3 local n
```

but I am getting this error:

```
pam@g3:~/.chainlink-kovan$ cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.3 local n
2021-04-07T09:36:21Z [INFO]  Starting Chainlink Node 0.10.3 at commit 5dbbc21f13fa00ee724c439273156834c45ab93e cmd/local_client.go:56  InstanceUUID=f51952e7-d4c9-45f5-b0ae-6e1ed5617bbb SHA=5dbbc21f13fa00ee724c439273156834c45ab93e Version=0.10.3 id=boot 
2021-04-07T09:36:21Z [ERROR] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=localhost user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address) orm/orm.go:82           stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/orm.NewORM
        /chainlink/core/store/orm/orm.go:82
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.initializeORM
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:250
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.newStoreWithKeyStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:87
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.NewStore
        /chainlink/core/store/store.go:66
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:135
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.ChainlinkAppFactory.NewApplication
        /chainlink/core/cmd/client.go:85
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
        /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:58
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:524
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:173
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:405
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:372
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:277
main.Run
        /chainlink/core/main.go:20
main.main
        /chainlink/core/main.go:14
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204 
creating application: failed to initialize ORM: initializeORM#NewORM: unable to init DB: unable to open postgresql://postgres:12345678@localhost:5432/postgres?application_name=Chainlink+0.10.3+%7C+ORM+%7C+f51952e7-d4c9-45f5-b0ae-6e1ed5617bbb for gorm DB: failed to connect to `host=localhost user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)
```

I thought this error is coming from `postgres`, so I tried to connect to `postgres` through `nodejs`, which worked.

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

const client = new Client({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "postgres",
  password: "12345678",
  port: 5432,
});

async function main() {
  await client.connect();
  console.log("Connection Successful.");

  return process.exit(0);
}
main();
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904185/running-a-chainlink-node-cant-connect-to-database, but this doesn't count as a duplicate because this is on stackoverflow instead of stack exchange. Nice work Anupam!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was arriving because I was running `postgres` on my local machine for which I have to add `--network host` in the end.

### Updated Command

```
docker run --name chainlink-kovan --network host -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.3 local n
```